# Angular: Error handling in HTTP request to receive a file

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, httprequest

I need to send a request to the server, and I expect the server to respond with either a file or an error message if something goes wrong. The issue is that I'm struggling to set up my request to handle both files and errors. How can I make this work?

**Service with request**

```
  export(id: string, poolsName: string[]): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.post<Blob | any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/item/${id}/export`, poolsName)
  }
```

**Component**

```
async fullExport(poolsName: string[]){

    if(this.projectId) {

      this.projectsService.export(this.projectId, poolsName).subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          console.log("res: ", response);
          // const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' });
          // const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          // const a = document.createElement('a');
          // document.body.appendChild(a);
          // console.log(url);
          // a.style.display = 'none';
          // a.href = url;
          // a.download = 'output.pptx';
          // a.click();
        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.log("error: ", error);
        }
      );
    }

  }
```

When executing a request, if it returns a file, I get this error in the browser console

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 201,
    "statusText": "Created",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/item/6310716b78015e32433ee34d/export",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/item/6310716b78015e32433ee34d/export",
    "error": {
        "error": {},
        "text": "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000�..."
    }
}
```

I tried adding { responseType: 'blob' } to the http request, and then the file is received normally, but if an error occurs, I cannot receive it.

Comment: >>When executing a request, if it returns a file, I get this error in the browser console<<
Http status 201 is not error status. I will suggest you to separate needed functionality to 2 parts. The first one - your POST, the second one - additional GET request to fetch needed data.

Comment: @EvgenyGurevich But why is it being caught in the error block rather than the response block?

Comment: @EvgenyGurevich So, you mean after executing the POST request, if it succeeds, to make a GET request to retrieve the file? That's a good idea; thank you.